# Как изменить свойство объекта или удалить css класс

Tags: javascript, jquery

Перепробовал уже разные варианты, но свойство не меняется. Ниже код:

```
<button onclick='hhh()'>jjj</button>
<div class='sss' id='kkk'>hello</div>
<script>
function hhh () {
    $('#kkk').css({'color':'green'})
}
</script>
```

И сам css код:

```
.sss {color:red}
```

Собственно при нажатии на кнопку цвет почему-то не меняется

Comment: а `jQuery` подключен?... Просто в код у Вас ситнтаксиса jQuery, а в тэгах ее нет...

Comment: Спасибо, я про него совсем забыл)))

Comment: вставил Ваш код в fiddle - все работает правильно. цвет меняется...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы удалить класс, используйте `removeClass()`

```
$('#kkk').removeClass('sss');
```

и ваш код у меня меняет цвет

Answer (score 2):

Метод для удаления класса без использования jquery.

```
// Передаваемые аргументы: element(Node), reClass(String).
var RemoveClass = function(element, reClass) {
    var _classes = element.className.split(' ');
        for (i = 0; i < _classes.length; i++) {
            if (_classes[i] == reClass) {
                _classes.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    element.className = _classes.join(' ');
}
```